# VBA runtime error 91: Object variable not set?

Tags: vba, excel

Why is this not working? Run time error 91?

```
Dim fornameCurr As String
Dim surnameCurr As String
Dim rowCurr As Long

rowCurr = 13
fornameCurr = Activesheet.Cells(rowCurr, 1)    << ERROR HERE
surnameCurr = Activesheet.Cells(rowCurr, 2)
```

Comment: How is this code being called? From Excel or from another application? Is it from an Add-in?  (If it's from Excel, not from an Add-in, then this code should work)

Comment: I am getting no issues with the code you have given.

Comment: What is the value in A13? Is it an error?

Comment: @Vityata that would raise a 13 Type Mismatch error, though, not a 91 Object error.

Comment: True, @DavidZemens. I will keep on guessing. @Slab, do you have `Option Explicit` on top? Is it somehow possible that you have declared `rowCurr` as a public variable or something?

Comment: "Curr" rings the "Currency" bell in my external reader's head. Avoid useless abbreviations and use meaningful names. What's wrong with `currentRow`?

Comment: even if `rowCurr` as public/module variable, the compiler uses the procedure level instance unless qualified otherwise (e.g., `Module1.currRow`) @Vityata :)

Comment: @DavidZemens, I said I am guessing :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug, yup, VBA can be confusing, if man tries to do to this way :)

Comment: It would help us help you if you can respond...

Comment: @DavidZemens I apologise, I only work part time, and I posted this just before going home on Monday UK time. My brain was melting and I couldn't work out this error as it was late in the day - but you have helped me realised my simple mistake. See my comment on the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Runtime error 91 suggests that `ActiveSheet Is Nothing` (because `ActiveSheet` is the only presumed *Object* in the few lines of code you've provided, and certainly the only *Object* on the line raising the error).

Several scenarios I can think of might contribute to this:

1. The code is being called from an Add-In, in Excel or another application, and no Excel workbooks are open. In this case, there is no `ActiveWorkbook` and also no `ActiveSheet`.
2. The code is being executed from another application (Outlook,
   Access, Word, PowerPoint, etc.), but you're using the Excel built-in
   `ActiveSheet` which doesn't exist in the other applications.
3. You've shadowed the built-in `ActiveSheet` with `Dim Activesheet As
   Worksheet` and neglected to assign a worksheet object to that variable, so it's `Nothing` by default.

Resolutions:

1. Add logic to check for presence of Workbook object, etc.
2. Declare a `Worksheet` object variable and assign to it.
3. Prefer to avoid shadowing existing built-in names, ensure assignment to the object variable

Comment: My guess is #2 -- but we really shouldn't have to guess. OP needs to provide more details.

Comment: It seems like he is trying to pass a location reference to a string, which makes me think thats the issue. fornameCurr = Activesheet.Cells(rowCurr, 1) <> Dim fornameCurr As String. Weird that he didnt get a data type mismatch error?

Comment: @DougCoats I don't follow what you're saying... `ActiveSheet.Cells(rowCurr, 1)` returns the `.Value` from that cell, which is convertible to String data type unless it's an Error (which would raise the Mismatch, instead).

Comment: @DavidZemens, I go with option 3... note how OP's code does not have 'sheet' capitalized, thus possibly he declared his own.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn yes I noticed that. Could be a typo but it did make me think of that possible error in shadowing the built-in `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: @DavidZemens Thank you, #3 is correct. I'd been staring at the screen for so long I missed something obvious. I had actually declared my own `ActiveSheet` - I called it `sheetActive` (however I realsied this might confuse people so I hurridly changed it back to `Activesheet` when typing the question and as you can see I forgot to capitalise the S of sheet) and declared and set it as public in another module - which I stupidly forgot to call at the start of this subroutine. It just goes to show you should never change code when asking a question as it may well be the relevent bit! Thanks all.